# Allowing WMA (from TTR package) to return original value when fewer than N points

Tags: r, plyr

When running the following:

```
wavData = ddply(wavData, c("primary", "interference", "label"), transform, 
                value = WMA(value,3,wts=1:3))
```

Some of the resulting groupings made by ddply do not have 3 points in them, thus I get the following error:

```
Error in WMA(value, 3, wts = 1:3) : Invalid 'n'
```

Question: How can I allow WMA to return the ORIGINAL values when n<3, and not crash?

Answer (score 1):

How about using `ifelse`?

```
wavData = ddply(wavData, c("primary", "interference", "label"), transform, 
            value = ifelse(length(value) < 3, value, WMA(value,3,wts=1:3)))
```

Comment: +1, but `ifelse` can be slow.  Since the individual elements of the result aren't affected, a simple if/else block would be faster: `value = if(length(value) < 3) value else WMA(value,3,wts=1:3)`